# Missing tick label from a plot of data indexed with a PeriodIndex

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I'm trying to plot two series and have the x-axis ticks labeled every 5 years. If I index the data with a `PeriodIndex` for some reason I get ticks every 10 years. If I use a list of integers to index, then it works fine. Is there a way to get the right tick labels with a `PeriodIndex`?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

np.random.seed(0)
idx = pd.PeriodIndex(range(2000,2021),freq='A')
data = pd.DataFrame(np.random.normal(size=(len(idx),2)),index=idx)
fig,ax = plt.subplots(1,2,figsize=(10,5))
data.loc[:,0].plot(ax=ax[0])
data.iloc[9:,1].plot(ax=ax[1])
ax[1].xaxis.set_major_locator(mpl.ticker.MultipleLocator(5))
plt.show()
```

[image: with PeriodIndex]

```
idx = range(2000,2021)
```

[image: with integer idex]

The workaround I know is to convert the `PeriodIndex` to `DatetimeIndex` and then to an array of `datetime.datetime`objects and use `plt.plot_date()` to plot and `mpl.dates.YearLocator(5)` to format. This seems overly complicated.